# Linting to detect unused exported variables

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I'm trying to figure out how to detect when a exported variable (const, function, ...) is not used and therefore could be deleted. I have a React App with ESLint configured.

In the following example, `MAGIC_NUMBER` is exported and used in file2.js but `doMagic` is never imported or used in any other file.

file1.js

```
export const MAGIC_NUMBER = 7;
```

file2.js

```
import { MAGIC_NUMBER } from "./file1.js"

export function doMagic() {
    return MAGIC_NUMBER + 1;
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way to detect that `doMagic` is unused.

Right now, I'm using ESLint with the the default rule :

```
"no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }]
```

It detects unused variables inside the same file, but not across multiple files.

Thank you very much!